# Retrieve columns based on headers

Tags: csv, awk

I have a .csv file with million rows, I want to retrieve columns based on header for example

headers: 300A 300B 300C 301 302 303 303A 303B 304 (file has 9 columns and million rows)

I'm unable to provide a command which can retrieve all the columns starting from 300B and between 304

Expected output: (need to retrieve the columns along with header)

300B 300C 301 302 303 303A 303B

Tried with basis awk and grep, giving output based on only .csv column number, unable to retrieve columns based on header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), you can run

```
mlr --csv cut -f 300B,300C,301,302,303,303A,303B input.csv >output.csv
```

Before starting test on million of rows, you could start with few rows

```
mlr --csv head then cut -f 300B,300C,301,302,303,303A,303B input.csv >output.csv
```

If you need to extract programmatically a range, you can use linux utilities. In example, running

```
<input.csv head -n 1 | grep -o -P '(?<=300A,).*(?=,304)'
```

you get `300B,300C,301,302,303,303A,303B`.

Create a bash script and use that command as input variable.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to extract all the columns between 300B to 303B without mentioning the name of each column?